# python request for here map api

Tags: python, api

I have pandas array, which in every row contain GPS coordinates and I want to find out the speed limit for this coordinates. For this issue I use HERES maps API like this.

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
   waypoint = df2['Latitude'] +','+df2['Longitude']
   payload = {'waypoint': waypoint, 'app_id': 'DemoAppId01082013GAL', 'app_code': 'DemoAppId01082013GAL'}
   r = requests.post('https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/getlinkinfo.json', params=payload)
   df2['res'] = r.text
```

But if I want to proceed more than 300 rows, than I receive response like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>414 Request-URI Too Large</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request-URI Too Large</h1>
<p>The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity
limit for this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

I use this API https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/routing/link-information-for-a-location

Thanks for help.

Comment: maybe you can't do more than 300 request a day without paying.

Comment: as for me this method can use only one `waypoint` but you use all data from `df2` as `waypoint` - maybe you should use `waypoint = row['Latitude']+','+row['Longitude']` and `row['res'] = r.text`

Comment: It was that problem, I should used only one row,not whole column in df2. Thanks for help!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

`params` argument to `requests.post()` makes parameters added to URL. Every server has a limit of characters that could be given as URL. Error message states it clearly.

You're getting `index` and `row` in the loop but do not use them. Instead `df2` is being used, seems to be a bug.

Anyway you may debug this easily just by printing this `waypoiny`

Answer (score 0):

This method can use only one `waypoint` but you use all data from `df2` as `waypoint` - you should use

```
waypoint = row['Latitude']+','+row['Longitude']
```

and

```
row['res'] = r.text
```